# TextMeshPro Text not changing, console is giving rapid errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cpp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Num : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int score;
    public TextMeshPro TMP;

    void Start()
    {
        TMP = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        score = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        TMP.text = score.ToString();
        score++;
    }
}
```

The text is not changing, and I dont know why. The error in the console is "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Num.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Num.cs:19)"

Comment: Are you sure there is a `TextMeshPro` attached to the **same** GameObject the `Num` component is attached to?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that your script isn't finding a `TextMeshPro` sibling component.  If you're using the UI version, what you actually want is to find a `TextMeshProUGUI`

Comment: if i use TextMeshProUGUI it wont let me put the text inside the object placement thingy (dont know what its called)

Comment: @Immersive but if OP is using `TextMeshPro` not the UI version he probably would like to get the `TextMeshPro` component, right? ....

Comment: @derHugo correct.  Answer was more of a "it can't find what you're looking for, are you looking for the right thing?"

Comment: @Immersive yes and that sounds more like a comment than an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a text ui from what you said. If it is a text UI and Textmeshpro, then use `TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI varName;`